# Error while mounting volume in azure container instance

Tags: azure, docker, azure-container-instances

I am trying to mount volume by following the tutorial on this link [Deploy container and mount volume - YAML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-volume-azure-files).
The relevant portion of yaml file is

```
volumeMounts:
      - name: filesharevolume
        mountPath: /home/indy/.indy_client/wallet/ 
        readOnly: false
```

```
volumes:
  - name: filesharevolume
    azureFile:
      sharename: acishare
      readOnly: false
      storageAccountName: xxxxxxxxxx
      storageAccountKey: xxxxxxxxxx
```

I am getting this error in container logs

```
 Caused by: Unexpected sqlite error
  Caused by: database is locked
```

[image: Folder inside the running container]

Comment: Can you share the YAML file you use?

Comment: @CharlesXu if i do --mount type=volume in docker than it work in docker but --mount type=bind give same error in docker, so my guess would be that volume mount is of type bind in azure as specifed in the notes of the azure link, so is there any way for mount type to be volume in azure

Comment: @CharlesXu https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/ , https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-volume-azure-files

Comment: Yes, you're right. ACI mount is similar to the Docker bind mount. But ACI does not have the feature to control the mount mode currently.

Comment: @CharlesXu So is there any other way to mount? Also thank for confirming.

Comment: As I know there is no other way to control it in ACI.

Comment: Does it solve your problem? If it works, do you mind I adding an answer to describe it?

Comment: yeah sure, go ahead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ACI mount is similar to the Docker bind mount. You can see the Note shows it in the link you provide and the Note. And ACI does not have the feature to control the mount mode. So as you guess, if the job needs to use the volume mode to mount the Azure File Share, then you cannot achieve it with ACI.